# TortoiseGit silent installation on windows

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am wondering if anyone installed TortoiseGit silently in windows providing all settings through some property file.

TortoiseGit provides ".msi" and it gets installed with **msiexec** but though we need to configure it manually once installed. I want to automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseGit can be installed silently.

Basically no configuration needs to be done afterwards.

- If git.exe is on the path is it detected on the first start automatically. Otherwise it can be set in registry on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit` and set it to the "bin"-folder of the Git for Windows installation to be used.
- The SSH-tool can be set using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit` and set to `[TGIT_INSTALL_DIR]\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe` or just `ssh.exe`.

Also see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-admins.html

Comment: Git silent installation: `msiexec /i TortoiseGit-<version>-<arch>.msi /quiet`.